# Freeswitch ESL client: application doesn't receive events from bLeg

Tags: java, netty, freeswitch

We have Freeswitch using ESL (async full) with a Java client application.
When an inbound call arrives, the application filters by **filter Channel-Call-UUID aLegUuid** and this inbound is usually bridged to a bLeg (bridge command with park_after_bridge). 
So we receive events from both legs in the same *Netty Channel Handler*.

As far as I know, in the same *Netty Channel Handler* we could receive events from different legs: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_event_socket

```
 filter plain all 
 filter plain CUSTOM conference::maintenance 
 filter Unique-ID $participantB 
 filter Unique-ID $participantA 
 filter Unique-ID $participantC
```

There is a case where bLeg, by pressing a DTMF, transfers (transer XML default) aLeg to 'fifo with MOH' and then bLeg dials another number. bLeg at this point in parked (park_after_bridge).

Before unbridge aLeg and bLeg, we apply another filter to listen events from A and B **filter Unique-ID aLeg** and **filter Unique-ID bLeg** but we receive events from B esporadically. Some test are fine and some not.

Insted, if we create an Inbound Connection to FS and apply the same filters, we receive events from A, B, before and after the bridge.

So, why do we not receive events from B in the main *Netty Channel Handler* after the bridge was broken, even with the filters applied?
How is the *Netty Channel* bound to just the events from A?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

After Freeswitch session on its HipChat, Mike Jerris pointed out the [piece of code](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/src/mod/event_handlers/mod_event_socket/mod_event_socket.c#373-378) that explain why this is not working as I expect:

```
if (send && switch_test_flag(l, LFLAG_MYEVENTS)) {
        char *uuid = switch_event_get_header(event, "unique-id");
        if (!uuid || (l->session && strcmp(uuid, switch_core_session_get_uuid(l->session)))) {
            send = 0;
        }
    }
```

> you will only see events for the call leg that called the socket app on an outbound socket connection

Thanks to "Matthew Vale (@Mafoo)" as well